# Non-defaulted operator <=> doesn't generate == and !=

Tags: c++, c++20, spaceship-operator

I'm running into a strange behavior with the new spaceship operator `<=>` in C++20. I'm using Visual Studio 2019 compiler with `/std:c++latest`.

This code compiles fine, as expected:

```
#include <compare>

struct X
{
    int Dummy = 0;
    auto operator<=>(const X&) const = default; // Default implementation
};

int main()
{
    X a, b;

    a == b; // OK!

    return 0;
}
```

However, if I change **X** to this:

```
struct X
{
    int Dummy = 0;
    auto operator<=>(const X& other) const
    {
        return Dummy <=> other.Dummy;
    }
};
```

I get the following compiler error:

`error C2676: binary '==': 'X' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator`

I tried this on clang as well, and I get similar behavior.

I would appreciate some explanation on why the default implementation generates `operator==` correctly, but the custom one doesn't.

Comment: The title makes it harder to reach this question when googling. Maybe should change to `non-defaulted operator <=> doesn't generate == and !=`. I happened to encounter the [motivation](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1185r2.html#motivation) behind [p1185r2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1185r2.html) and was going to ask a similar question and answer it myself.

Comment: I would like to keep this question open, because I find the answer containing the Specs quote much better then the answers to the non-dup'd question.

Comment: I came here from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77981799/spaceship-operator-for-type-representing-a-compile-time-constant-stdstring-vie?noredirect=1#comment137479080_77981799. It's a shame compilers don't have a nice explicit error for this. It wouldn't be hard and it would be very helpful: `...did you mean to add bool operator==(const X&) const = default;`?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

This is by design.

> **[class.compare.default]** (emphasis mine)
>
> [4](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.compare.default#4) If the class definition does not explicitly declare an `==`
> operator function, but declares a **defaulted three-way comparison
> operator** function, an `==` operator function is declared implicitly
> with the same access as the three-way comparison operator function.
> The implicitly-declared `==` operator for a class X is an inline
> member and is defined as defaulted in the definition of X.

Only a defaulted `<=>` allows a synthesized `==` to exist. The rationale is that classes like `std::vector` should not use a non-defaulted `<=>` for equality tests. Using `<=>` for `==` is not the most efficient way to compare vectors. `<=>` must give the exact ordering, whereas `==` may bail early by comparing sizes first.

If a class does something special in its three-way comparison, it will likely need to do something special in its `==`. Thus, instead of generating a potentially non-sensible default, the language leaves it up to the programmer.

Comment: It's certainly sensible, unless spaceship is buggy. Potentially grossly inefficient though...

Comment: @Deduplicator - Sensibility is subjective. Some would say a silently generated inefficient implementation to be not sensible.

Answer (score 63):

During the standardization of this feature, it was decided that equality and ordering should logically be separated. As such, uses of equality testing (`==` and `!=`) will *never* invoke `operator<=>`. However, it was still seen as useful to be able to default both of them with a single declaration. So if you default `operator<=>`, it was decided that you also meant to default `operator==` (unless you define it later or had defined it earlier).

As to [why this decision was made](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1185r2.html#motivation), the basic reasoning goes like this. Consider `std::string`. Ordering of two strings is lexicographical; each character has its integer value compared against each character in the other string. The first inequality results in the result of ordering.

However, equality testing of strings has a short-circuit. If the two strings aren't of equal length, then there's no point in doing character-wise comparison at all; they aren't equal. So if someone is doing equality testing, you don't want to do it long-form if you can short-circuit it.

It turns out that many types that need a user-defined ordering will also offer some short-circuit mechanism for equality testing. To prevent people from implementing only `operator<=>` and throwing away potential performance, we effectively force everyone to do both.

Answer (score 28):

The other answers explain really well why the language is like this. I just wanted to add that in case it's not obvious, it is of course possible to have a user-provided `operator<=>` with a defaulted `operator==`. You just need to explicitly write the defaulted `operator==`:

```
struct X
{
    int Dummy = 0;
    auto operator<=>(const X& other) const
    {
        return Dummy <=> other.Dummy;
    }
    bool operator==(const X& other) const = default;
};
```

Note that the defaulted `operator==` performs memberwise `==` comparisons. That is to say, it is not implemented in terms of the user-provided `operator<=>`. So requiring the programmer to explicitly ask for this is a minor safety feature to help prevent surprises.

Comment: And maybe note that the defaulted `operator==` is not using `operator<=>`.