# Why should I use the three-way comparison operator (<=>) instead of the two-way comparison operators? Does this have an advantage?

Tags: c++, c++20, comparison-operators, spaceship-operator

```cpp
#include <compare>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{ 
   auto comp1 = 1.1 <=> 2.2;
   auto comp2 = -1 <=> 1;
   std::cout << typeid(comp1).name()<<"\n"<<typeid(comp2).name();
}
```

**Output:**

> struct std::partial_ordering
> struct std::strong_ordering

I know that if the operands have an integral type, the operator returns a **PRvalue** of type `std::strong_ordering`. I also know if the operands have a floating-point type, the operator yields a **PRvalue** of type `std::partial_ordering`.

But why should I use a three-way comparison operator instead of two-way operators (`==`, `!=`, `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`)? Is there an advantage this gives me?

Comment: Here's something that you can read http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0515r2.pdf by the big man himself.

Comment: It depends on the context I would say. If you're creating a class, implementing `operator<=>` (or even `default`ing if possible) saves time (development and maintenance) instead of having to implement _all_ of them manually. If you on the other hand are interested in knowing `if( 1.1 < 2.2 )`, then it probably doesn't make much sense to use `<=>`

Comment: Less code to write using 2 comparison operators `<=>` and `==`.  Less chance of having a mistake/bug than writing 6 comparison operators.

Comment: Are you asking about using `<=>` **to perform** a comparison, or about using `<=>` in any general context?

Comment: @DrewDormann Actually both

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It makes it possible to determine the *ordering*  in one operation.
The other operators require two comparisons.

Summary of the other operators:

- If `a == b` is false, you don't know whether `a < b` or `a > b`
- If `a != b` is true,  you don't know whether `a < b` or `a > b`
- If `a < b` is false, you don't know whether `a == b` or `a > b`
- If `a > b` is false, you don't know whether `a == b` or `a < b`
- If `a <= b` is true, you don't know whether `a == b` or `a < b`
- If `a >= b` is true, you don't know whether `a == b` or `a > b`

A neat side effect is that all the other operators can be implemented in terms of `<=>`, and a compiler can generate them for you.

Another side effect is that people might be confused by the use of `<=>` as the equivalence arrow in mathematics, which it has been pretty much since typewriters got those three symbols.
(I'm personally pretty miffed by how `a <=> b` is "truthy" if and only if `a` and `b` are *not* equivalent.)

Answer (score 11):

The main advantage (at least for me) is the fact that this operator can be defaulted for the class, which will automatically support all possible comparisons for your class. I.e.

```
#include <compare>

struct foo {
    int a;
    float b;
    auto operator<=>(const foo& ) const = default;
};

// Now all operations used before are defined for you automatically!

auto f1(const foo& l, const foo& r) {
    return l < r;
}

auto f2(const foo& l, const foo& r) {
    return l > r;
}

auto f3(const foo& l, const foo& r) {
    return l == r;
}

auto f4(const foo& l, const foo& r) {
    return l >= r;
}

auto f5(const foo& l, const foo& r) {
    return l <= r;
}

auto f6(const foo& l, const foo& r) {
    return l != r;
}
```

Previously, all those operations would have to be defined within the class, which is cumbersome and error-prone - as one would have to remember to revisit those whenever new members are added to the class.

Answer (score 6):

Use your own judgment.

The point of the spaceship operator is *not* specifically for comparing objects. The main point of it is permitting the compiler to synthesize the *other* comparison operators from the spaceship operator.

If you don't specifically need to answer the question less-than, equal-to, or greater-than, then you don't need to invoke it directly. Use the operator that makes sense for you.

But should you need to make a type comparable, you only have to write 2 functions (spaceship and equality) rather than 6. And when writing such a function, you can use the spaceship operator on the individual types in question (should they be comparable in such a way). That makes it even easier to implement such functions.

The other useful thing that the spaceship operator allows you to do is tell what *kind* of ordering a comparison will provide. Partial, strong, or whatever. This can theoretically be useful, but it's fairly rare overall.

Comment: ... and if spaceship is `default`ed, you don't even need to write `operator==`

Comment: _you only have to write 2 functions (spaceship and equality)_ I wonder whether equality couldn't be based on the spaceship operator as well (like all the other relational operators). I always was under the impression of that.

Comment: @Scheff: Only if you `= default` it. [Types where  you need to explicitly define a comparison operator usually have short-circuit versions if you only care about equality testing.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61492875/734069) So if you user-define one, you need to user-define the other one (which you could do in terms of the spaceship easily enough).

Answer (score 5):

The *spaceship* operator was proposed by Herb Sutter and was adopted by the committee to be implemented with C++ 20, detailed report can be [consulted here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0515r2.pdf), or you if are more into lectures, [here you can see a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ULkwKsag0Yk) of the man himself making the case for it. In pages 3/4 of the report you can see the main use case:

The comparison operators implementation, needed for pre C++20, in the following class:

```
class Point
{
    int x;
    int y;

public:
    friend bool operator==(const Point &a, const Point &b) { return a.x == b.x && a.y == b.y; }
    friend bool operator<(const Point &a, const Point &b) { return a.x < b.x || (a.x == b.x && a.y < b.y); }
    friend bool operator!=(const Point &a, const Point &b) { return !(a == b); }
    friend bool operator<=(const Point &a, const Point &b) { return !(b < a); }
    friend bool operator>(const Point &a, const Point &b) { return b < a; }
    friend bool operator>=(const Point& a, const Point& b) { return !(a < b); }
    // ... non-comparisonfunctions ...
};
```

Would be replaced by:

```
class Point
{
    int x;
    int y;

public:
    auto operator<=>(const Point &) const = default; 
    // ... non-comparison functions ...
};
```

So to answer your question, overloading `operator<=>` as class member allows you to use all comparison operators for the class objects without having to implement them, defaulting it also defaults `operator==`, if it's not otherwise declared, which in term automatically implements `operator!=`, making all comparison operations available with a single expression. This functionality is the main use case.

I would like to point out that the *spaceship* operator would not be possible without the introduction of [the ***default comparison*** feature](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_comparisons) with C++20.

> #### Defaulted three-way comparison
>
> [...]
> Let `R` be the return type, each pair of subobjects `a`, `b` is compared as follows:
> [...]
> ... if `R` is `std::strong_ordering`, the result is:
>
> ```
> a == b ? R::equal : a < b ? R::less : R::greater
> ```
>
> Otherwise, if `R` is `std::weak_ordering`, the result is:
>
> ```
> a == b ? R::equivalent : a < b ? R::less : R::greater
> ```
>
> Otherwise (`R` is `std::partial_ordering`), the result is:
>
> ```
> a == b ? R::equal : a < b ? R::less : b < a ? R::greater : R::unordered
> ```
>
> Per the rules for any `operator<=>` overload, a defaulted `<=>` overload will also allow the type to be compared with `<`, `<=`, `>`, and `>=`.
>
> If `operator<=>` is defaulted and `operator==` is not declared at all, then `operator==` is implicitly defaulted.

It also allows to default `operator ==` only, which will implement `operator !=`, albeit not as versatile as the former, it's also an interesting possibility.