# generate == operator that uses non-defaulted <=>

Tags: c++, c++20, spaceship-operator

In a slight variation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58780829/4588453). I would like to define a custom type with a custom `<=>` operator and use that custom `<=>` operator to generate a `==`. Trying the following

```cpp
#include <compare>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

struct widget {
  int member;
  int non_comparison_data;
  friend std::strong_ordering operator<=>(const widget& lhs,
                                          const widget& rhs) {
    std::cout << "doing a three way comparison" << std::endl;
    return lhs.member <=> rhs.member;
  }
//   friend bool operator==(const widget& lhs, const widget& rhs) {
//     return 0 == (lhs <=> rhs);
//   }
  friend bool operator==(const widget& lhs, const widget& rhs) = default;
};

int main() {
  widget a{.member = 1, .non_comparison_data = 23};
  widget b{.member = 1, .non_comparison_data = 42};
  assert(a==b);
  return 0;
}
```

I observe that a default `==` operator does not use the custom `<=>` operator, but instead does what would be done in absence of any custom comparison and compares all data members. I can define an operator `==` on my own that uses `<=>` like follows, but I'm wondering if there's a better way to get `==` out of `<=>`.

```cpp
friend bool operator==(const widget& lhs, const widget& rhs) {{
  return 0 == (lhs <=> rhs);
}
```

PS: [compiler-explorer link](https://godbolt.org/z/9srxPz)

PS: I'm aware a custom `<=>` doesn't generate a default `==` because `==` is likely implementable in a more optimal way than using `<=>` and one does not want an inefficient default to be generated.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm wondering if there's a better way to get == out of <=>.

Nope, there's not.  What you did (`return 0 == (lhs<=>rhs);`) is the optimal way.  What more were you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to define `==` in terms of `<=>` is to do it manually. Which is what you're already doing.

You can do a little bit better by writing member functions (the only benefit of non-member `friend`s would be if you wanted to take by value. But if you're not doing that, member functions are easier - simply less code to write). And then implement `==` forwards instead of backwards... no Yoda conditionals please.

```cpp
struct widget {
  int member;
  int non_comparison_data;

  std::strong_ordering operator<=>(const widget& rhs) const {
    return member <=> rhs.member;
  }

  bool operator==(const widget& rhs) const {
      return (*this <=> rhs) == 0;
  }
};
```

Comment: for the `friend` part, i was told in review to keep binary operators free `friend` functions in compliance with core guideline C.86 https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rc-eq

Comment: @pseyfert The description there says "`B`’s comparison accepts conversions for its second operand, but not its first" but that is no longer true in C++20. So the guideline (make `==` symmetric) is trivially satisfied with member functions (as long as you remember both `const`s).

Comment: bool operator == using operator <=>;  in C++23 please ;)

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl No.