# Which operators implictly define / generate other operators in C++?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, c++20

I know that defining certain operators in C++ lets the compiler generate other operators for a class. From what I read [in this cppreference article](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_comparisons) it seems like the following holds true:

1. `operator==` must be explicitly defined (perhaps as default) to be usable.
2. `operator!=` is generated from `operator==` if it is not defined explicitly and `operator==` is defined.
3. `operator<=>` generates the other four relational operators (if all goes to plan, that is `operator<=>` returns a result possible to interpret by the other four and is well defined for both the original and reverse parameter orders)
4. `operator<=>` does NOT generate `operator==` even if it returns `std::strong_ordering` which, as I understand, should return an object comparable as equal to `0` if and only if the two compared objects are identical (indistinguishable). I tested this myself with the following code

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
public:
    int x;
    int y;

    // Lexicographic ordering but by the y member first, and by x second.
    std::strong_ordering operator<=>(const Foo& other)
    {
        if (std::strong_ordering cmp = y <=> other.y; cmp != 0)
            return cmp;
        return x <=> other.x;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo f = {1, 1}, g = {1, 0};
    std::cout << (f == g);
}
```

which returns error `no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘Foo’ and ‘Foo’)`.

What I want to know is, first of all, WHY DOESN'T `operator<=>` generate `operator==` and secondly -- is there a complete list of which operators generate other operators (and which ones), or is that cppreference article complete in that regard and there are no other operators being generated? For instance I'd expect `operator+(Foo)` and `operator-()` to generate `operator-(Foo)`, on the basis that subtracting is nothing but adding the additive inverse. This, however, turns out to be untrue, which I also tested.

Comment: FYI: [SO: non-defaulted operator <=> doesn't generate == and != in C++20](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58780829/7478597)

Comment: Ah, thank you for that link. It also made me remember a line I saw in the cppreference article: "If operator<=> is defaulted and operator== is not declared at all, then operator== is implicitly defaulted.", which I did not understand before and promptly forgot about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which operators implicitly define / generate other operators in C++?

There is only one situation in which one operator defines/generates another, and that is when you *default* `operator<=>` you *also* get a defaulted `operator==`. That's the complete list.

Everything else is not based on declaring operators, it is based on rewriting expressions:

- it's not that an `operator!=` is generated from `operator==`, it's that the expression `x != y` also tries to evaluate as `!(x == y)`
- it's not that an `operator<` is generated from `operator<=>`, it's that the expression `x < y` also tries to evaluate as `(x <=> y) < 0`

In your case, `f == g` simply has no `operator==` candidate, so it's ill-formed. The original design of `<=>` also would try to rewrite this expression as `(f <=> g) == 0` (again, not generating `operator==` but rather rewriting the expression). But this was shown to have [serious performance issues](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1190r0.html) and so it was [changed to not do this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1185r2.html). You can read more about Comparisons in C++20 [here](https://brevzin.github.io/c++/2019/07/28/comparisons-cpp20/).

In this case, since you're doing member-wise comparison, you can simply:

```cpp
bool operator==(Foo const&) const = default;
```

or write it manually if you prefer. Either way, your `operator<=>` is missing a `const` - it's important that the comparison operators be symmetric.

Comment: Thanks for the insight about what actually happens with `operator!=` and the four comparison operators. Thanks also for the sources you linked regarding performance. Finally, it's good that you noticed my missing const, although that was the result of sloppy testing.