# Member spaceship operator with an arbitrary argument type - is it supported?

Tags: c++, c++20, spaceship-operator

Why does the following code not compile (`no match for 'operator=='`)? Is this syntax allowed? If yes, how to fix the code? If not, where does the standard say that?

```
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
struct VectorWrapper {
    using ValueType = std::vector<T>;

    constexpr auto operator<=>(const VectorWrapper&) const noexcept = default;
    constexpr auto operator<=>(const ValueType& otherValue) const noexcept {
        return v <=> otherValue;
    }

    ValueType v;
};

bool f() {
    VectorWrapper<int> v;
    return v == std::vector {0};
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/1jh9z7G7E

Comment: The suggested duplicate does not answer anything. This one is more like it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58780829/non-defaulted-operator-doesnt-generate-and-in-c20

Comment: Both duplicates answer "why posted code does not compile?" These do that more or less in same manner, one quotes normative text, other gives links to background information why normative text is such. So I proposed the latter, as it felt deeper answer.