# Spaceship operator for type representing a compile-time constant std::string_view

Tags: c++, c++20

I have a class that represents a compile-time constant string. I'd like it to act like a string in that it has an implicit `operator std::string_view() const noexcept { return "foo"; }`. I'd like it to have `operator<=>` to compare with all the string-like types including `std::string_view`, `const char*`, and `const std::string&`. I can make it work, but I have to provide more operators than I expect. Can someone explain why?

If I have

```
//! A monostate class representing the string "foo":
struct Foo {
    constexpr operator std::string_view() const noexcept {
        return "foo";
    }

    //! Make it compare with itself.
    friend constexpr auto operator<=>(const Foo&, const Foo&) = default;
};
```

then I can only compare with itself and with `std::string_view`. That makes sense to me, because the conversion operator lets comparison with `std::string_view` try to convert the `Foo` into a `std::string_view`.

So then I think "We need to be comparable with anything that compares with a `std::string_view`." so I add

```
    //! Comparison with anything that compares with a std::string view?
    friend constexpr auto operator<=>(const Foo& foo, const auto& other) {
        return static_cast<std::string_view>(foo) <=> other;
    }
```

and it allows `operator<` and `operator<=>` in either direction with `const char*` and `std::string`, but not `operator==`.

If I add

```
    friend constexpr bool operator==(const auto& other, const Foo& self) {
        return other == static_cast<std::string_view>(self);
    }
```

then everything compiles. Why is that needed? In particular, I thought `operator<=>(const T&, const U&)` allowed me to compare those two types for equality (in either order). Is that wrong? Adding `operator<=>` in the other order doesn't help.

https://godbolt.org/z/6G3aszM4v

Comment: The `=default`ed `==` is never implemented in terms of `<=>`, because that's slow (e.g. when comparing strings, `==` can compare lengths first and exit early if they're different, `<=>` can't). Defaulting `<=>` implicitly defaults `==`, but it doesn't implement it in terms of `<=>`; `==` still compares the fields directly.

Comment: Also you might want to make your operators SFINAE-friendly (`decltype(...)` instead of `auto` in the return type should do it).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I see, so the defaulted `<=>` provides self-`operator==`, but the explicit `operator<=>(const Foo& foo, const auto& other)` does not, so with `operator<=>(const Foo& foo, const auto& other)` I can do `(Foo{} <=> "foo") == 0` but not `Foo{} == "foo"` because that would be a hidden perf penalty, hence I need to provide both versions? Re: SFINAE, how about `const std::convertible_to<std::string_view> auto& other`?:  https://godbolt.org/z/o66WMoWxY

Comment: *"would be a hidden perf penalty"* Yeah. `convertible_to` looks good to me.

Comment: If you make that an answer, I'll mark it resolved.

Comment: It's probably a duplicate, that's why I'm not making a full answer.